# using sscanf to get input from a string

Tags: c

I am getting the following string as input from the user: `"id,name,age,grade,country,city"`

-id consists of digits 0-9 only
-name consists of a-zA-z letters
-grade consists of digits 0-9 only
-country consists of a-zA-z letters, white spaces and '-' dashes.
-city consists of a-zA-z letters, white spaces and '-' dashes.

I am trying to speharete each field into its own string.

my code is:

```
char id[MAX_STRING_SIZE], name[MAX_STRING_SIZE], grade[MAX_STRING_SIZE], age[MAX_STRING_SIZE],
                    country[MAX_STRING_SIZE],city[MAX_STRING_SIZE];

sscanf(userInput,SEPARATOR,id,name,grade,age,country,city);
```

where `userInput` is a string in the form `"id,name,age,grade,country,city"`

and `const char SEPARATOR[] = "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,\n],%s";`

however, this code breaks with certain inputs, such as `"id,,age,grade,country,city"`

Comment: And why is that a problem? Thats an invalid input. Just check `sscanf` return value and issue an error message if the input is invlaid.

Comment: Why are you doing this?  If you already have the string, there's (probably) no need to make additional copies of all the data.  Just parse the string!  Iterate over the string and look for commas (or use `strchr`), replace them with '\0', and set the pointer.  Or even use `strtok`.  Using `strtok` is usually a mistake, but it's better than the using sscanf for this.

Comment: @Eraklon because I need to know in which field I have a problem.. your solution is not going to work

Comment: @WilliamPursell scanning char by char? that hell of alot of code to write!

Comment: @willhunting1337 Then it would be wise to phrase the question in a way so it is clear what exactly you want. What is your expected output/behaviour for the invalid input.

Comment: @Eraklon As I said. I want to split each parameter into a sepharate string. 
sscanf sadly doesnt work for all cases.

Comment: @willhunting1337 Much better to write 10 lines of code than to spend hours debugging scanf issues.

Comment: scan will tell you how many fields it successfully parsed.  You can assume the error is with the field that it didn't parse, or you can abandon scanf and parse the string.

Comment: @WilliamPursell mind showing how to handle it in 10 lines? haha

Comment: @willhunting1337 see my answer below... less than 10 significant lines of code which produce a nice little array of strings, one for each field in your input.

Comment: @willhunting1337, in a comment, I'll have to do it in one line: `char *t = userInput; id = strsep(&t, ","); name = strsep(&t, ","); age = strsep(&t, ","); grade = strsep(&t, ","); country = strsep(&t, ","); city = strsep(&t, ","); if ( id == NULL || ...) die( "invalid input");`

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you could do instead of sscanf, as suggested by @WilliamPursell

```
char* field[6];
field[0] = userInput;

for (int n=0, i=1; userInput[n] && (i < sizeof(field)/sizeof(field[0])); ++n)
{
    if (userInput[n] == ',')
    {
        userInput[n] = '\0';
        field[i] = &userInput[n+1];
        ++i;
    }
}
```

It might be necessary to make a copy of userInput first