# Trying to read a specific format from a file

Tags: c

Hello I'm trying to read a specific format from a file and put the values I need in a 2d array.

This is the format “timestamp1”: “value1”, “timestamp2”: “value2”, … , “timestampN”: “valueN”

I need the timestamps and values not the quotes.

The insight of the file
[image: could be inserted as text, but the OP didn't make it]

Every new line equals to a new day.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DAT_MAX_LINES 1000

int main(void)
    {
        char array[DAT_MAX_LINES][2];
        int n = 0;
        int i;

        FILE * pRead = fopen("tempm.txt", "r");

    if (!pRead)
    {
        printf("File cannot be opened\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Contents of tempm.txt:\n");

    while ( (n < DAT_MAX_LINES) && (!feof(pRead)) )
    {
        fscanf(pRead,"\"%s\": \"%s\",%n", &array[n][0], &array[n][1]);
        n++;
    }

    fclose(pRead);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\" %s\",%n", i, array[i][0], array[i][1]);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

For the start I will take the values as strings and then convert the values as doubles.I'm not sure if I can do it from the start.

Answer (score 0):

The `%s` conversion specifier doesn't look ahead in the pattern, just because you follow the specifier with a quite won't make the actual conversion stop when it finds a quote.

You can use `%[]` for that, but it's quite brittle to build parsers like that using `fscanf()`. If it's truly line-based, consider reading whole lines using `fgets()`, the parsing those.

Comment: I would actually go as far as to say that using `fscanf()` with `%s` is always wrong (as is `%[]` or anything else which reads an unknown number of characters into a buffer). Using `fgets()` is pretty much always a better approach.

Comment: Is it possible to give me an example with a code?Should i use the sscanf?

Comment: @Joe You could use a combination of `fgets()` and `sscanf()`, but in this case i would recommend processing the string in several stages. You could start with `fgets()`, then split the line at the commas using `strtok()`, and then parse only those substrings with `sscanf()` or split again at the `:`. Another option would be to parse it manually, where you could save a pointer to the next character whenever you encounter a leading `"`, and replace the corresponding trailing `"` with `\0`.

Comment: @Joe You can also check out my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61122803/using-sscanf-to-get-input-from-a-string/61123662), which deals with a similar (albeit slightly less complex) problem

Comment: Can i go with something like this? https://i.imgur.com/4Wpnz87.png

Comment: @Joe There is pretty much no chance that `%d` will parse your timestamp format correctly. Also, please don't post screenshots of code, but rather edit your original question and post the code as text.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to declare 2 array for storing the values and timestamp:

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 1000 // for example
#define MAX_NUM_VALUES 4000
...
char timestamps[MAX_NUM_VALUES][MAX_LENGTH];
int values[MAX_NUM_VALUES];
```

Try to read line by line by using `fgets()`:

```
char line[MAX_LENGTH];
while ( fgets(line, sizeof(line), pRead))
{
    // get value in each line
}
```

After get line by line from text file, you can use `strtok` to separate the line by comma `,`, then using `sscanf` to get timestamp and value in each line.

```
    while ( fgets(line, sizeof(line), pRead))
    {
        char * token = strtok(line, ",");
        while(token != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", token);
            sscanf(token," \"%s\": \"%s\"", timestamps[n], &value[n]);
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
            n++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello after a while i managed to read from the file the specific format and i put it all together in an array.Now i want to remove the quotes,and make a 2d array with the timestamps and values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
   char c[100000];
   FILE *fptr;
    if ((fptr = fopen("tempm.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error! opening file");
        // Program exits if file pointer returns NULL.
        exit(1);
    }

     //reads text until newline is encountered
    fscanf(fptr, "%[^\n]", c);
    printf("Data from the file:\n%s",c);  //raw data of the file
    fclose(fptr);

   int i=0;
   char *MixedArray[10000];
   char *token = strtok(c, ",");
   while( token != NULL ) {
      MixedArray[i]=token;
      token = strtok(NULL, ",");
      printf("%d %s\n",i,MixedArray[i]);
      i++;
  }
     return 0;
}
```

My results:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i2ms.png
Not enought rep to post image